# Cassandra : How query with secondary index and clustering keys range work

Tags: cassandra

Ex:

In Table A, id is partion key and time is clustering key and deviceid is secondary index

Query 1) `Select * from A where  id=1234 and time > xx and time < vv and deviceid='dddd';`

How this query works?
I have enable tracing .

It is  first filtering secondary index and then filtering range.I was expecting the reverse.

Does the above work impact performance?

Comment: Just as a side note: Secondary indexes in Cassandra are not like they are in traditional dbs. They actually will ultimately make the performance of the cluster worse or flat out wont work at scale unless used very carefully. They are not there for query optimization. Dont think of it the same way as in a RDMS and in most likelihood avoid unless absolutely necessary and you fully understand why.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Cassandra will use the same plan for both the queries.

You can use `TRACING ON` command in cql to look at the plan that cassandra uses to fetch the records.

They will be same in both the cases.

Because partition key is used only single node will be referred in both the cases.

Comment: But we are using first secondary index and then partition key.